# delay in calling the angularjs service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I've a service in which i'm making a POST call through `$http`. I'm calling this method from a different function in a controller, I've several lines of code written in the function of my controller which I want to execute after the service call, though I'm calling the function in the beginning of my method in controller it is getting executed at the end. I don't see any errors in the console, what could be the reason. Has anyone ever faced this issue?

Comment: Give the code for better understanding. But I guess you need to use callback in the service and put remaining calls in the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a callback function that returns your data from the $http call.  Inside this callback run the code you want executed before you update your scope with data returned from the $http call.

**Why this is happening:**

You are making the $http call first, but while it is posting the data your other lines of code are running before the $http call has time to return and update your scope.